# org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Couldn't determine the boundary from the message

Tags: postman, jax-rs, cxf

I have created apache cxf rest webservice having both json and file in request. I am testing it through Postman. Not able to include both json and file in a single post request.

Structure of post request:

```
    @Path("/file/both")
    @Consumes("multipart/mixed")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @POST
    public String addBookFile(@Multipart("thejson") JsonPOJO request,  @Multipart("document")Attachment att) {
        return "filename:" + att.getContentDisposition().getParameter("filename");
    }
```

The issue may be in how I call the service from Postman.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6ibF.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELI0P.png)